# How could you protect a Dyson Shell?

Tags: science-based, dyson-spheres

As you may or not be aware, we have a wonderful bubble created by the Sun. This Heliosphere (or bubble) protects us from plasma and other debris coming at us from the interstellar medium.

I have read a lot of threads on Dyson Shells and none seem to address what to do in the absence of our lovely Heliosphere.

## Answers will be separated into two categories:

### Dyson Shell proposals that allows for a Heliosphere to stay intact

### Dyson Shell defense proposals.

NOTE: My ideal Dyson Shell is only about 3 million miles in radius (just over .03227 of an AU) due to heating and resource problems, as opposed to the typical 1 AU Dyson shell. The proposals do not have to take this size into account, but it is always a bonus.

Comment: I am not entirely sure that I understand what you're looking for in an answer.. What criteria make an answer a *good* answer? And what do you mean by spreading them into different categories?

Comment: Are these two different questions? What exactly defines "intact" for you in this case? And what is a "Dyson Shell defense proposal" supposed to be about? I think this question might get put on hold as it is in my opinion unclear what your asking. This is a standard procedure on this site to edit a question together with the community so that it fits the scope of the site. A question that is put on hold can be reopened after some edits were made.

Comment: What are you trying to protect the dyson shell from?  Alien invaders, meteor strikes, space pirates siphoning off power?

Comment: Dyson Sphere = "Infinite" energy = Big Lasers :)

Comment: "... Heliosphere (or bubble) protects us from plasma and other debris ..." plasma partly, but you wouldn't notice the difference, anything else not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe talks about how to shed excess energy from a Dyson sphere in [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/70849/32987).

Instead of constantly dumping that energy into the far reaches of space, use that energy-beam energy dissipation model but store sufficient store energy in capacitors to fuel beam weapons.